# Can two actors both required for a usecase be the same person?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have been presented with the following use case diagram.

[image: Activity case]

The given question was "How many people are required for the Use Case?".

I was taught, that *Actors* are used to model certain roles in the domain and that a "real" person can take multiple roles.

Going strictly by that definition, a single person with both roles should be enough, but I am not sure whether I am missing something, since intuitively there should be a reason, why there are two actors present.
Can a single "real" person be enough here?

Comment: warning to use the right naming / tags, you used "UML Activity Diagram" in the question and associated tag rather than "use case diagram"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to assume that actors are people. However this is not the case: an [actor](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html) can be another system interacting with the subject of your use case.

So strictly speaking, if A and B would be systems, then no people would be required at all.

But even if all actors in the diagram would be  humans: the [multiplicity of actors](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor-association.html) in your diagram is not specified. This creates an ambiguity.  Most people assume it means `1`, i.e. `1..1`, i.e. a mandatory actor. As Axel explained in the comment, this would be the correct interpretation of the UML specs (it's not written black on white, but some inferences allow to deduct it).  However many people also used to represent an association of a use-case with all primary actors that can possibly be involved without explicitly mentioning a `0..1` optional multiplicity (probably because it was newly introduced with UML 2.5).  Therefore, in practice there is still an ambiguity if both actors are really mandatory.

Finally, as you already rightly analysed and Bruno confirmed, even if both actors would be required it could be the same person.

Comment: I agree that most people are wrong, when they think it means 1. 

However, the next most common misconception is, that it means unspecified. 

Actually it means, the modeler didn't care to mention it in the diagram. We have to look in the model to find out. 

There we might find, that it is in fact unspecified. And - suprisingly - that means 1. 

It means 1, because there is a derivation for attributes `lower` and `upper`, that evaluates to 1 in case of unspecified `lowerValue` and `upperValue`. Of course you could still argue, that there is a difference between implicit and explict 1.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Now I see your point and have found the references.  It is subtle, because no default value is defined, and you have to go in the operations, to find the operation that derives /lower to realize that it would be 1..1. -  However, given the many UC that use a more flexible semantic, the diagram stays ambiguous, not because of the specs, but because of a popular practice:  we cannot be for sure what the modeler meant without explicit multiplicity.  I edited the answer and gave you the credit.  I guess you are the kind of person who reads small print in every contract ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.

For instance imagine a system allowing to trace bugs in a software, the actors can be

- user : person adding a new bug report in the system to signal the problem
- corrector : person correcting the bug

[image]

In case the bug detected in intern by the persons developing the software are traced a same person of that team can have the two roles

---

In my forum when a user requests to register I manually accept or not the registration to reject spammers

[image]

be sure to test I played the role of both a user and the administrator

Etc, there are lot of cases like that